# Is it ok to mix slf4j and Log4J code in a project

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

It's a bit complicated but I think it is not uncommon

I have a legacy project using `Log4J` all along without slf4j, so code change to replace `log4j` to `slf4j` is impossible.

However the project has a dependency, which code with `slf4j`, but the pom file includes `slf4j`, `slf4j-log4j` bridge and `log4j`.

My question is, whether all can work out if I just add the `slf4j`, `slf4j-log4j` dependencies in the main project pom and everything can still work out with single log4j.properties?